# Facebook Login equivalent on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth

I am developing an app that needs to query (READ) AWS details on behalf of end users who would use my app. For example, dashboard view of all EC2 instances running across on availability zones for that user's AWS account.

Facebook has oAuth which lets developers perform actions on behalf of a user, does AWS has similar services to let developers query or even make changes on behalf of a AWS User? (For example, Stop a EC2 instance running under the user's AWS account)

Comment: Could you please update your Question to add more details about what you mean by "query AWS details on behalf of end users"? What AWS details? What do you mean by "changes on behalf of an AWS User"? Adding more details to your question will likely result in better answers.

Comment: For example, in my dashboard, I want to be able to display a list of EC2 instances for user's AWS account. 

(this is just an example, I know this information is already available on AWS console)

Answer (score 0):

Permissions would need to be granted to perform actions on a particular AWS Account.

For example, if you wanted to view or stop an Amazon EC2 instance in *my* AWS account, I would need to provide credentials to you so that you could make the API call. This could be done by creating a permanent **IAM User** for you, or I could generate temporary credentials using the [Security Token Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html) -- these are time-limited credentials created from permanent credentials, that can be assigned limited permissions.

**Bottom line:** Whoever owns the account would need to provide you with credentials.